# Uploading image to firebase storage doesn't work in Electron js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, electron, firebase-storage

I am using Electron js with Next js for my web app and I want to be able to upload images and display it in the app using firebase. Uploading data to the firestore database works but uploading an image to the firebase storage doesn't work for some reason. The image just doesn't get uploaded at all no matter how long I wait. I have refreshed the firebase storage page multiple times but the image never turns up. There is also no error code to say why it has failed. I have already tested my code in codesandbox and it works there but not in my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-minsky-wytrk9?file=/src/App.js. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using Electron js because I have no idea why the code can upload to firebase storage in codesandbox, but not my app. I have also tried using uploadbytesresumable in my app but it still doesn't work.

My rules for storage:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some security rules?

Comment: @AlexanderN. I added my rules for the storage.